# How to make External Bank account as default account in Stripe Connect?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am adding external bank account in stripe account through its library, and i want to make account as default account from my side in Stripe. So can any one help me whether it is possible or not. I have already referred Stripe connect APi. But i can not find any solution for that.

Below is the link which i am using.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_update_bank_account

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what you are trying to accomplish and where you are having trouble? You can update an external account to be the default for its currency(https://stripe.com/docs/api/#account_update_bank_account-default_for_currency). If you're not using Connect and this is just for your own account, you can use https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payouts

Comment: solved from my side. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution as described by @Yuri but it did not work for me.

This is the solution which did work:

```
    Account::updateExternalAccount($merchant_id, $bankAccId, [
        'default_for_currency' => true
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I need do this from API my solution.

```
$account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve("acct_1D3pnBDRbcBW58lj");
$bank_account = $account->external_accounts->retrieve("ba_1DTppmDRbcBW58ljE9hni34m");
$bank_account->metadata["default_for_currency"] = true;
$bank_account->save();
```